# How can I compare a single number to items in a list of numbers?

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement

`X` is a single number. Essentially I want to check in the list `listaa` to know if `x` is less than or equal to any element in `listaa`. I have,

```
if x <= listaa.any():
            continue
```

Comment: Lists by themselves don't have an `any()` method. But There is an built-in `any` function that you can use a generator expression to check your condition against all the list items and pass it to the `any()`. Like `any(x <= i for i in listaa)`.

Answer (score 4):

Just check if your value is less than or equal to the maximum of your list:

```
if x <= max(listaa):
    continue
```

If you wish to use `any`, you can use a generator expression. It's a [built-in function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) rather than a list method.

```
if any(x <= i for i in listaa):
    continue
```